# ¿Se puede ejecutar mas de una sentencia sea true o false en un operador ternario en PHP?

Tags: php, php7

Quiero usar un operador ternario para ejecutar dos sentencias en caso de que sea verdadero o falso.

```
($texto == "ejemplo") ? ($valor = "value"; function($valor)) : ($valor = "value"; function($valor););
```

¿Saben si el operador ternario solo permite ejecutar una sola sentencia sea true or false?

Comment: Hola prox, ¿es ese el caso que realmente estas necesitando resolver? por que para _ese caso_ hay una solución bastante más simple.

Answer (score 3):

Si, se puede, agrupas cada "acción" entre paréntesis y las concatenas usando punto.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
($condicion) ? 
  ($var1 = 'x') . ($var2 = 'y') . (fn1('a')) 
  : ($var1 = '1') . ($var2 = '2');
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://onlinephp.io/c/dc2e5)

Comment: Yo no lo uso, no me gusta, considero que es una forma de "ofuscar" código.